# How to use `self` as a function, like `self(**data)` in the example code

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is part of code from [mmcv](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv) (mmcv/runner/base_module.py).

I don't understand how does `self(**data)` works.

```
class BaseDetector(BaseModule, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Base class for detectors."""

    # ...

    def train_step(self, data, optimizer):
     
        losses = self(**data)
        loss, log_vars = self._parse_losses(losses)

        outputs = dict(
            loss=loss, log_vars=log_vars, num_samples=len(data['img_metas']))

        return outputs
```

```
class BaseModule(nn.Module, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, init_cfg: Optional[dict] = None):
    # ...
```

Tried to find some function like `__call__` in the parent class, but it seems not the right direction to go.

Could any one explain why `self` could be used as a function?

Comment: `self` in this case is callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing specific to PyTorch but rather to how Python works.

"Calling" an object is equivalent to calling a [special Python function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) named [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__). Essentially, this is the function which implements the *call* behaviour. In your case `self(**data)` will call `BaseDetector`'s `__call__` function which has most probably been implemented by one of the parent classes.

Here is a minimal example to understand this behaviour:

```
class A():
    def __call__(self):
        return 'hello'

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return self() + ' world'
```

Initialize a new object from `B`:

```
b = B()
```

Then let us call the `foo` method on `b`:

```
>>> b.foo()
'hello world'
```

This function has been calling `b()` *i.e.* `b.__call__()`:

```
>>> b() # same as b.__call__()
'hello'
```

---

As an additional note, you can explicitly call the implementation of the parent class. This is useful when you need to overload the original implementation in your child's class.

It is done by calling [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super):

```
class A():
    def __call__(self):
        return 'hello'

class B(A):
    def __call__(self):
        # calling self() here would create an infinite recursion loop
        return super().__call__() + ' world'
```

Then you can call an instance of `B` the same way:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b()
'hello world'
```

Comment: Thanks! Found `__call__ : Callable[..., Any] = _call_impl` in pytorch's class `Module`. `_call_impl` is the function which calls `forward` function of class `BaseDetector`